# An example of incompleteness?

Tags: number-theory, logic, incompleteness

Is it fair to suggest that the fact a base's symbol which would exist in a higher base but is never truly reflected in the base itself is an example(see below) of incompleteness along the ideas of the theorems? My apologies as I'm mostly self-teaching in these areas and feel I've skipped a lot of interim understanding. I don't know logic notation yet so can't follow any raw work. My example would be as follows;

In binary, base 2, we only ever feature the numbers 0 and 1 in all our numerical representations. Despite the fact it's base 2 the numerical symbol of 2 itself never actually appears in this system as this is instead 10.

Is this an example of the theories of incompleteness? Have I just made a random naive or arbitrary correction or is this a fair conclusion of sorts, if even very simplistic? Thanks in advance.

Comment: "random naive" seems to sum it up pretty well.

Comment: The word incompleteness,as it is usually used, doesn't have much to do with symbols

Comment: Thanks, thats fair! So this can't in anyway be sensibly related to incompleteness at all?

Comment: "Is this an example of the theories of incompleteness?" No. It has nothing at all to do with incompleteness in the logical sense. The binary number system is perfectly capable of expressing all natural numbers. There is nothing surprising in the observation that in any base, there is a limit to what can be expressed with a single digit number. On the other hand, the incompleteness theorems were very surprising indeed.

Comment: Having said that, there is a weak analogy in what you suggest, and analogies, even if weak, can potentially aid intuition, as long as you don't press the analogy too far.

Comment: Thanks John, it came to mind in a discussion with a friend(I couldn't frame my understanding of the haltimg problem and resorted to this) and I knew it was rather weak. I used arithmetic in the example as a simple subset, not intending a wider extrapolation, but this is all rocky territory I'm trying to understand more. Thanks for the insights.

Comment: You are conflating *objects* and *symbols*. The number *two* is the object that has the symbol $2$ as name in the decimal system and the symbol $10$ as name in the binary system.

Comment: I do understand that, but I dont agree its as simple as that. 10 is a composite symbol made of 1 and 0 which will have appeared in the system previously, 2 is a single item. To put it another way, when people see '10' will they think 'ten' or 'two*'? *or equivalent base translations. I realise this far divervges from the point. I do understand Russell's paradox and the Halting problem in essence, I struggle more with a good but understandable analogy for incompleteness theorem(even if simplified/specific over general)

Comment: If i tried to maybe define it differently? Within tbe arithmetic theres a set of single-digit numbers, and thus the set of all non-single digit numbers. I'm of the assumption that any base n system will have n-1 'single-digit numbers' in it. Yet why can the system never contain a 'single-digit number' to represent n itself?

Answer (score 9):

Incompleteness (in the logical sense) is not about representation of mathematical objects. Rather, it concerns the relation of truth and provability in mathematics, where the latter concepts are understood in a specific technical sense.

There is no good metaphor which fully capture it. Douglas Hofstadter made an attempt in *Gödel, Escher, Bach: An Eternal Golden Braid*, which I recommend.

My advice is to begin by learning formal logic. Otherwise, it will be like trying to understand quantum physics without learning calculus or any other physics.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, now the 6th recommendation to me for that book and ironicially one that was brought up by my friend when I tried to think about this with him.

Comment: The book is very good. It was an inspiration for becoming a mathematician.

Comment: I have started on the Peano axioms/logic which will eventually go a long way. Unfortunately I know a few physicists already and do understand more about quantum physics than I should! I was formally educated in maths and physics until 18 though. Tbh I'm long term chasing maths that naturally crosses over (just for the enjoyment tbh)

Comment: Are you able to translate the incompleteness problem onto a more plaintext argument for a layman? Thats what im struggling with. I understand it to the extent of essentially that a formally rigid and complete system cannot be accurate because it has no room to deal with undefined terms, whereas an incomplete system can deal with and address unknowns due to iterative processes and thus it can be accurate, but it has to be incomplete because by definition because we cannot define the unknown until its...somewhat known?

Comment: Incompleteness is not about terms, knowledge or rigidity. It is about the possibility establishing the *truth* of arithmetical propositions via *formal proofs*.

What it states is the following. If a formal system is such that (1) it's consistent, (2) it is strong enough to describe (a fragment of) Peano arithmetic, then (3) it cannot prove it's own consistency.

Comment: Excuse me popping up again but would it be fair to say this? hypotehtical first idea of logic is that 'things' are actually then 'this thing' and 'not this thing'. we then define our logic and axioms by the idea of 'this thing' because its obviously patently absurd to define it with a term it isn't. ie yellow is yellow but then if you asked me what green was and i said simply not yellow it is valid and defined but arguably incomplete for red blue etc

Comment: ie it would be peculiar for me to define something as 'this thing is not THIS thing' because it only tells you what it isnt as opposed to what it is. to unite it generally for valid soundness I'd have to form it as 'this thing is not that thing' introducing differentiation and arguably a dimension that did or did not exist before(impossible to tell before differentiation?). ofc i cheated here and did differentiate to add a dimension in capitalizing my second 'this' to start with. However on the scheme of things is this a valid analogy of sorts to incompleteness?

Comment: Not really, because what you seem to be thinking of are definitions and denotations. That is, you're thinking about how one describes and pinpoints things in the world (colors, numbers, tables, and so on.)

Incompleteness is about *mathematical truth* and *formal proofs*. That is, you're dealing with properties of mathematical propositions, not of things or concepts.

Comment: I see. Does mathematics not suffer from the same eventually though and thus the incompleteness? Is it fair to summarise the incompleteness problem quite naiively in suggesting we construct all our 'proofs' within a system we cannot technically construct a proof of itself? Was this not what Godel essentially did, utilising mathematics to disprove(or rather prove by contradiction) that it can prove everything? Thus is incomplete?

Comment: ie lets suggest 0 is absolute 0 (black/#000000) is absolute blue(#0000FF if you like) and 2 is yellow (#FFFF00 if you like). everyone knows that of both, but they may have different names to different people but we have them across the world. Forget increments or 2 coming after 1. The world over knows and recognises these things(assume we are all standard). Why is there a difference between maths and that? Aren't colours numbers tables etc all a subset of the maths axioms and definitions that form the proofs?

Comment: The incompleteness theorems state, among other things, that when a logical system becomes strong enough to formulate arithmetic (that is, elementary number theory), one cannot prove the consistency of the logical system using a finitary proof system. So in a sense, your first description is correct. However, you keep returning to naming of objects. Incompleteness is not about that at all.

Comment: I think I see. Maybe i confuse objects somewhat with sets etc (again im super self-taught/exploring on these things). I just don't particularly see enough difference between numbers operators operands etc other than symbolic representations of values and processes. Then however I consider transcendentals like pi and e which seemingly cant be represented by anything simpler in the system beyond a formula or infinite series. This makes me think...what did we do before them? And what if we have another value next? like i for example?